# Why does |A| = |B| IFF A bij B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

I don't understand why the mapping lemma states that |A| = |B| IFF A bij B.

My understanding of the above lemma is

If A bij B is True then |A| = |B| is True

If A bij B is False then |A| = |B| is False

If |A| = |B| is True then A bij B is True

If |A| = |B| is False then A bij B is False

My understanding is most likely incorrect so please correct my understanding of the mapping lemma:

This mapping lemma is invalid by providing this counter example.
A = {1,2,3}.
B = {4,5,6}.
There is no relation between set A and B.

With this example,
|A| = |B| is True since 3 = 3.
However A bij B is False since there is no relation between them.
This means that in this counter example, (|A| = |B| IFF A bij B) = (T IFF F) = F

I am almost certain my understanding and counter example are wrong but can someone kindly point out where I made a mistake in my understanding and example? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the first point is to understand what you mean when you says "they are not in relationship"

Comment: I suspect $A\text{ bij }B$ stands for: a bijection $A\to B$ exists. Then evidently $\{1,2,3\}\text{ bij }\{4,5,6\}$.

Comment: What makes you say there is no bijection between $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6\}$? I can easily come up with a half-dozen of them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well chosen terminology ;-).

Comment: I think that a first step would be the understand what does it mean for two sets to have a bijection between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comment under Kenny Lau's answer, I think the problem is the following: that you are assuming that a bijection between two sets needs to be "meaningful" in some way. This is not the case: bijections don't need to follow some pattern, they're allowed to be completely arbitrary.

Indeed, the existence of a bijection between two sets is usually how "having the same cardinality" is *defined*; really what we're doing here is arguing that this formal definition matches our usual intuitions about cardinality.

*There is a philosophical point here - to what extent can mathematical objects "exist" without being "definable" - but it's not really relevant here: two sets have the same cardinality iff there is a bijection between them, regardless of what "is" means. Perhaps two different notions of mathematical existence could disagree about whether a bijection exists between two particular sets, but both notions will separately agree that "equicardinality = bijection."*

Answer (score 5):

$x \mapsto x + 3$ is a bijection $A \to B$.

Comment: That makes sense. However, what if B = {1,2,4} or something more difficult like B = {‘dog’, True, 7^(1/10)}?

Comment: @user10121076 Come on now. Define $f:A\to B$ by $f(1)='dog'$, $f(2)=True$, $f(3)=7^{1/10}$.

Comment: I was thinking that but I wasn’t sure if it was correct. It seemed forced but it is right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective on a bijection is that it is a function F: X -> Y, such that there exists an inverse function G: Y -> X.  So, for every element x in X, we have G(F(x)) = x, and for every element y in Y we have F(G(y)) = y.

Cardinality is trichotomous in that either |X| < |Y|, |X| = |Y|, or |X| > |Y|.

So, for a set X with a bijection F from X to Y, suppose that |X| < |Y|.  But, then there exists some y in Y such that F(G(y)) = y is false.  Thus, F is not a bijection.  We have a contradiction, so |X| = |Y| or |X| > |Y|.

Suppose that for the same set with a bijection F from X to Y that |X| > |Y|.  But, then there exists some x in X such that G(F(x)) = x is false.  Thus, F is not a bijection.  We have a contradiction, and we conclude that |X| = |Y|.